# Reading text file to array

Tags: python, string, file-read

I am trying to read a file into an array, my current implementation is only returning the first line of the .txt file

```
import re
def GetText(filename):
print('Opening file...')

text_file= open(filename,'r')
lines = text_file.readlines() #each line is appended to a list

with text_file:
    one_string= text_file.read().replace('\n', '')
print(one_string)
```

My question is: **How do I read a text file to an array?**

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: What makes you think after using `readlines()` and reaching the end of file , you would get anything other than empty string from `text_file.read()` ?

Comment: IanAuld: He is trying to read sentences rather than just the lines of the file...

Comment: Its not appending to a new list separated by each sentence

Comment: Use a context manager to handle the file! Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the whole file a line at atime why not read it all in one go and then split based on full stops (periods) in order to get sentences... ie:

```
text_file= open(filename,'r')
data=text_file.read()
listOfSentences = data.split(".")
```

Comment: `He sighed, "Sure. Fine. Whatever."` would not split evenly along the `.` character.